# Simple MySQL query to associate images

Tags: mysql, database

i need to get all images from database using query

for example

```
name ------ files
a    ------ a.txt
b --------- b.jpg
c ......... c.mp4
```

i need whole records which have extension .jpg

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE files REGEXP '.jpg$'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE files LIKE '%.jpg'
```